# How to solve this App crash [UIWebView webThreadWebView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:] + 92

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

How to solve this crash?I have spend three days in solving this issue,this crash is hard to reproduce,Can you give me any suggestion?Thanks you.
The photo is Fabric crash logs:
Crashed: WebThread  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010`

0

```
libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 16
```

1

```
UIKit-[UIWebView
webThreadWebView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:] + 92
```

2 `WebKitLegacy`

```
CallResourceLoadDelegateInWebThread(void (*)(), WebView*,objc_selector*, objc_object*, objc_object*, objc_object*, objc_object*) + 72
```

25

```
 libsystem_pthread.dylib     thread_start + 4
```

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520674/exc-bad-access-in-uiwebview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you so much,your post works,We have to set the webview's delegate as nil when the delegate dealloc.Because the delegate is assign,no weak for the UIWebView.